# Flot Time series not formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, flot

I am using flot to display a stacked time series in an mvc3 webpage. The graph displays correctly the xaxis formatting are not effecting the graph.

I pass the data to the view with the following code

```
    var range = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
        var graphData = _db.UpdateStatistics.Where(x => x.Day > range).OrderBy(x=> x.Day);
        var viewGraph = new SubscriptionUpdatesGraphViewModel();

        foreach (var entry in graphData)
        {
            viewGraph.Total.Add(new Tuple<long, int>(entry.Day.Ticks, entry.Total));
            viewGraph.Attention.Add(new Tuple<long, int>(entry.Day.Ticks, entry.Attention));
            viewGraph.Complete.Add(new Tuple<long, int>(entry.Day.Ticks, entry.Complete));
            viewGraph.Fail.Add(new Tuple<long, int>(entry.Day.Ticks, entry.Failed));
            viewGraph.Notify.Add(new Tuple<long, int>(entry.Day.Ticks, entry.Pending));
        }


        ViewBag.Graph = viewGraph;
        return View(result);
```

While on the view I have the following

```
<script id="source" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var total =  @ViewBag.Graph.SerialisedTotal;       
    var attention =  @ViewBag.Graph.SerialisedAttention;  
    var notify =  @ViewBag.Graph.SerialisedNotify;     
    var complete =  @ViewBag.Graph.SerialisedComplete;     
    var fail =  @ViewBag.Graph.SerialisedFail;    

    var stack = true, bars = false, lines = true, steps = false;

    function plotWithOptions() {
        $.plot($("#graph"), [{label:'Need Attention',data:attention}, 
                             {label:'Ready to apply',data:notify},                             
                             {label:'Failed',data:fail},
                             {label:'Completed',data:complete}], 
            { series: {stack : stack, 
                       lines: { show: lines, 
                                fill: true, 
                                steps: steps }  , 
               xaxis: {mode: 'time' ,                                                                           
                        timeformat: "%d",  
                        tickSize: [5, "day"]  }   }
        });
    }

    plotWithOptions();

});
```

The graph seems to display the raw ticks and nothing else

[image: The graph seems to display the raw ticks and nothing else]

example data:

```
    var total =  [[634754880000000000,12],[634755744000000000,10],];  
    var attention =  [[634754880000000000,2],[634755744000000000,0],]; 
    var notify =  [[634754880000000000,2],[634755744000000000,10],];   
    var complete =  [[634754880000000000,3],[634755744000000000,10],]; 
    var fail =  [[634754880000000000,5],[634755744000000000,0],];
```

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?

Comment: Post one of your data sets (i.e. what are the x,y values in your `total` variable)...

Comment: I added sample data, and I'm using version 0.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of small problems, but you're basically there.

First of all your timestamps are not valid timestamps, if you go `new Date(634754880000000000)` in your js console, that will return an invalid date.

You can use this to generate the timestamps in .NET (this is just pulled directly from the flot API.txt):

```
    public static long GetJavascriptTimestamp(DateTime input)
    {
        var span = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Parse("1/1/1970").Ticks);
        var time = input.Subtract(span);
        return time.Ticks / 10000;
    }
```

The second problem is that your call to $.plot is slightly off, the xaxis is not a member of series, but is at the same level as series, so like this:

```
$.plot($("#graph"),
        [{label:'Need Attention',data:attention}, 
        {label:'Ready to apply',data:notify},
        {label:'Failed',data:fail},
        {label:'Completed',data:complete}],
        {
            series: {
                stack: stack,
                lines: {
                    show: lines,
                    fill: true,
                    steps: steps
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%d"
            }
        });
```

With those two changes I was able to get your graph to output correctly.

Comment: This gives me correct time but incorrect date(day and month). Any ideas why? (25.08.2014 converts to 1.7.2014 in flot)